# Apple keeps asking me to accept the new iCloud terms and conditions

Tags: iphone, icloud

A pop-up will appear on my phone asking me to accept the new terms and conditions. To turn off these notifications, I need to turn off iCloud. Unfortunately, when I go into my settings to turn off iCloud, it requires me to accept the new terms and conditions in order to even turn off iCloud!

Does anyone know another way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could call apple care to turn off icloud for you. This would take a couple of hours to accomplish so I suggest you accept the  T&C and than log out from icloud via 'settings > icloud' like @Buscar said.

Answer (score 4):

Since you had the iCloud turned on initially, you will have to accept the T&C anyway.

You have a iCloud account!

Turning it off now is to late since you used the product already.

Comment: *> you will have to accept the T&C anyway ... Turning it off now is to late since you used the product already.* Why? He was using it under the old terms. He agreed to the old terms. While Apple is within their rights to cancel service if he does not agree to the new terms, they *cannot* force him to agree to the new terms. He can choose to discontinue use of the service - and that seems to be his intention.

Comment: @Bob you are right, he does not have to accept the T&C, however Apple has the right to continue ask for it. The use of service has already been initiated, the discontinuing does not remedy the request for T&C acceptance. He can delete his iCloud account from his device but not from icloud.com

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers solved my problem on iOS 9. I have multiple iCloud accounts configured on my phone, which was the root of the problem. I followed the instructions posted [here](https://positek.net/icloud-tc-hell/) and my problems were solved. For posterity's sake, here is an excerpt from that link:

> There’s not a lot of chatter about this, primarily because it only
>   affects a few few iPhone/iPad users who happen to have and use more
>   than one Apple ID on their device. This is you, so here’s how to fix
>   this:
>
> 1. Tap Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars, and then tap on the first iCloud account. You should see a Terms and Conditions link near the
>      top in blue.
> 2. Tap the link, scroll to the bottom and tap the Accept link.
> 3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 for any other iCloud accounts you have showing in the list of accounts.

Comment: Good point that some people mix multiple accounts on the same device.